# How to pass :new as parameter to oracle customer function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass :new from trigger to my custom oracle function,I had tried everything but failed.
Here is my code:

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace function sum_evaluation_onerow(arow in t_attend_j301%rowtype)
return number
as
total number:=0;
begin
  total:=trans_attend_type(arow.class12)+total;
  total:=trans_attend_type(arow.class34)+total;
  total:=trans_attend_type(arow.class56)+total;
  total:=trans_attend_type(arow.class78)+total;
  total:=trans_attend_type(arow.class90)+total;
  dbms_output.put_line(total);
return total;
end;
/

create or replace trigger tg_insert_attend_j301
after insert on t_attend_j301
for each row
declare
  total number;
  myrow t_attend_j301%rowtype;
begin
  --total:=sum_evaluation_onerow(:new);
  myrow:=:new
  update u_j301.t_stud_j301 set sum_evaluation=sum_evaluation where sno=:new.sno;
end;
/
```

What should I do?

Comment: you have to assign each field separately, ie, :new.field1, :new.field2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each attribute of the `%ROWTYPE` individually:

```sql
create or replace trigger tg_insert_attend_j301
after insert on t_attend_j301
for each row
declare
  total number;
  myrow t_attend_j301%rowtype;
begin
  myrow.sno := :new.sno;
  myrow.class12 := :new.class12;
  myrow.class34 := :new.class34;
  myrow.class56 := :new.class56;
  myrow.class78 := :new.class78;
  myrow.class90 := :new.class90;
  total:=sum_evaluation_onerow(myrow);

  update u_j301.t_stud_j301
  set   sum_evaluation=total
  where sno=:new.sno;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8a44fbfc71fa876bd1293d937cb8b25)*